# powershell - grab banner if port is open

Tags: powershell-2.0, port-scanning

I've been able to grab the http banner using the Web-Request using PowerShell 2.0. Now  I am trying to enumerate open ports and if open, grab the banner.  I'm able to get all the open ports - here is what I have to grab the banner.  it does not work - I get the error "the operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets".

```
  $socket = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient
  $result = $socket.BeginConnect($hostname, $port)
  $success = $result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne($timeout, $true)

   if ($success)
    {
        echo "open"
        $stream = $socket.GetStream()  // have also tried $stream = $result.GetStream()
        $buffer = new-object System.Byte[] 1024
        $encoding = new-object System.Text.AsciiEncoding
        while ($stream.DataAvailable) {
              $read = $stream.Read($buffer, 0, 1024)
               ......  // output data then close stream....
```

What am I doing wrong?